# Specify Which Column Comes First SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am processing a large list of church members in order to send them a letter. We want the letter to say "Dear John & Jane Smith". We will use Word to do the mail merge from an Excel sheet. The important thing is the male name has to always come first.

Each individual has their own row in the table I am using. They have a unique ID as well as a family ID. I am using that family ID to put families together on the same row. Currently I have the male name and the female name separated using `MAX(CASE WHEN)` in order to specify what goes where. It looks something like this:

```
+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| family id | male name  | female name |  last name |
+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
|      1234 | john       | jane        |  doe       |
|      1235 | bob        | cindy       |  smith     | 
|      1236 | NULL       | susan       |  jones     |
|      1237 | jim        | NULL        |  taylor    |
+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
```

But I run into a problem when the family only has one member.

Here's a part of the query I have:

```
SELECT
fm.family_id AS 'Family ID',
MAX(CASE WHEN PB.gender like 'm' and FM.role_luid=29 THEN PB.nick_name END) 
AS 'Male Name',
MAX(CASE WHEN PB.gender like 'f' and FM.role_luid=29 THEN PB.nick_name END) 
AS 'Female Name',
PB.last_name AS 'Last Name',

FROM core_family F
```

I was thinking that I need to combine rows using `STUFF` or something like that, but I'd need some way of specifying which column comes first so that the male name always comes first. Essentially, as stated above, I need the letter to read "Dear John & Jane Smith" for families with two people and "Dear John Smith" for families with one person. So I am hoping my results might look like:

```
+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| family id | First name   | last name |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|      1234 | john & jane  | doe       |
|      1235 | bob & cindy  | smith     | 
|      1236 | susan        | jones     |
|      1237 | jim          | taylor    |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your intermediate table (assuming you don't have 3 names for a family id).

From the table you indicated use:

```
select
 id
 , coalesce(male_name+' & '+female_name,male_name, female_name)
 , last_name 
from F;
```

[Here is an example with your data](http://rextester.com/BEAC43241)

Basically if you concatenate using `+` in Sql Server you will get null.  So if either male or female name is `NULL`, you get `NULL`.  Coalesce will move on to the next value if it sees `NULL`.  This way you either get a pair with `'&'` or a single name for each family.

Comment: Perfect! This did exactly what I needed. I figured I would need a temp table or something, but I did not think of using the '+' and then each column again. Here's what the query to the temp table ended up looking like:
    `SELECT
    coalesce(ml.male+' & '+ml.female, male, female) AS 'First Name',
    ml.[Last Name],
    ml.Street,
    ml.City,
    ml.State,
    ml.[Postal Code]
    FROM #ML ml

    DROP TABLE #ML`

Answer (score 0):

I've created some test data. This technique works with the test data.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (FamID INT, 
                      MaleName VARCHAR(20), 
                      FemaleName VARCHAR(20), 
                      LName VARCHAR(20))

INSERT #Temp
VALUES  (1234, 'John'  ,'Jane'   ,  'Doe' ),
        (1235, 'Bob'   , 'Cindy' , 'Smith'),
        (1236 , NULL  , 'Susan' , 'Jones'),
        (1237 , 'Jim'   , NULL  , 'Taylor')
```

Here is your query.

```
SELECT  FamID, 
        ISNULL(MaleName+' ','') +
          CASE WHEN MaleName IS NULL OR FemaleName IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'and ' END+ 
        ISNULL(FemaleName,'') AS FirstName, 
    LName
FROM #Temp
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this

```
SELECT                                
fm.family_id AS 'Family ID',
    MAX(CASE WHEN PB.gender like 'm' and FM.role_luid=29 THEN PB.nick_name END)  
 + '&'+      
MAX(CASE WHEN PB.gender like 'f' and FM.role_luid=29 THEN PB.nick_name END) 
AS 'First Name',
    PB.last_name AS 'Last Name',
    FROM core_family F
```

Comment: This works to combine names, but I am getting NULL in the First Name field for families with one person.